# Django REST framework TokenAuthentication returns anonymous user

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, http-token-authentication

How do I properly implement DRF TokenAuthentication without the request object returning an anonymous user when I try to log in?

according to the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication), when authenticated, the `TokenAuthentication` object provides the `request.user` which is the Django user instance and the `request.auth` which is the token instance. But even after authentication, `request.user` returns anonymouse user.

What could I be doing wrong?

**Client request:**

```
//function to get token
export default function axiosConfig() {
    // request header
    const headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

    // Get token from local storage. Token is stored when user registers.
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

    if (token) headers["Authorisation"] = `Token ${token}`;

    return headers;

}
```

Redux action

```
import axiosConfig from "../../utils/axiosConfig";

const config = axiosConfig

export const login = (email, password) => (dispatch, getState) => {

    const body = { email, password };

    // Change to absoulte path when deploying to production
    axios
        .post("http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login", body, config())
        .then((res) => {
            dispatch({
                type: SIGN_IN_SUCCESFUL,
                payload: res.data,
            });
            console.log(res);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            dispatch({
                type: SIGN_IN_FAIL,
                payload: err.response,
            });
            console.log(err.response.data, err.response.status);
        });
};
```

### Django

**url:**

```
from django.urls import path
from authentication.views import RegisterationView
from authentication.views import LoginView
from authentication.views import LogoutView

urlpatterns = [
    path("auth/register", RegisterationView.as_view()),
    path("auth/login", LoginView.as_view()),
    path("auth/logout/<int:id>", LogoutView.as_view()),
]
```

**Serializer:**

The `LoginResponseSerializer` is used to provide response data to the client

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """Login serializer"""

    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField(required=True)


class LoginResponseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            "id",
            "username",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "email",
            "is_active",
            "is_staff",
        ]

        read_only_fields = ["id", "is_active", "is_staff"]
```

**View:**

```
class LoginView(APIView):
    """Login View"""

    permision_classs = [permissions.AllowAny]

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = LoginSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            print(serializer.data) # Data is present

            user = authenticate(request, **serializer.data) # Valid credentials. User object is returned.
            response_serializer = LoginResponseSerializer(user)

            if user is not None and login(request, user):
                print(request.user) # User is anonymous

                token, created_token = Token.objects.get_or_create(user_id=user.id)

                if isinstance(created_token, Token):
                    token = created_token

                return Response(
                    {
                        "user": response_serializer.data,
                        "status": {
                            "message": "user authenticated",
                            "code": status.HTTP_200_OK,
                        },
                        "token": token.key,
                    }
                )

            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                "Invalid Username or Password. Please try again"
            )

        return Response(
            {"error": serializer.errors, "status": status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN}
        )
```

Comment: Can you also show your middlewares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Token authentication, your users will be authenticated with the token in the header, for each request.

Django `login()` is useful in case of SessionAuthentication. Where user is stored in the session object in django, identified by the session cookie.

In your view, you don't have to call the login method. Just return the `token` and whatever extra information you want. And make sure you are sending this `token` in every request to authenticate this user.

EDIT:
And the clarification about the `request.user` in the documentation of DRF, is about accessing the authenticated user in the other view where you provide token in headers.

Comment: @Sedan A. You're right. I later realize I was implementing the TokenAuthentication as thought it was a SessionAuthentication. Token auth only needs to verify the token and return the appropriate response. I removed  `login()` and discarded SessionAuthentication from the  `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` list in `setting.py` because it was before TokenAuthentication and that interrupted the flow.